# What is the criteria that Windows uses to display Update counts?

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I am tiring to write a Powershell script that will return the count of Windows Updates available the same way that Windows returns the count.  The problem that I am having is that I can't get my count to match the count that Window's Update returns.

For example my script may return:
Critical Count: 0
Important Count: 1
Optional Count: 30

But Windows Update will say that there are:
Critical Count: 1
Important Count: 1
Optional Count: 29

Does anyone know what criteria Windows uses to display the the counts in Windows Update?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
# ----- Get All Assigned updates --------
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search('IsInstalled=0')

# ----- Matrix Results for type of updates that are needed --------
$critical = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq "Critical" }
$important = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq "Important" }
$optional = $SearchResult.updates | where { ($_.MsrcSeverity -ne "Critical") -and ($_.MsrcSeverity -ne "Important") }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running this, not sure if it will solve your problems or not. I don't have a powershell accessible atm.

```
#Get All Assigned updates in $SearchResult
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0")


#Matrix Results for type of updates that are needed
$Critical = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq "Critical" }
$important = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq "Important" }
$other = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq $null }

#Write Results
Write-Host "total=$($SearchResult.updates.count)"
Write-Host "critical=$($Critical.count)"
Write-Host "important=$($Important.count)"
Write-Host "other=$($other.count)"
```

Comment: Michael - I used your code as it was and I couldn't get a return for critical, important, and other. I took the search criteria and the "$_.MsrcSeverity -eq $null" and used in my code but the results did not match what Windows returned.  My code: C=0,I=0,O=31 Windows returns C=0,I=1,O=30. The one update that is reported different between my code and Windows is update KB2600217 which is listed but not checked in the Important section. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Eskimo I'm sorry, I don't know a whole lot about this subject. Here are a few links that may be helpful.  
  
http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/01/27/managing-windows-update-with-powershell.aspx  
  
http://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/windows-updates-4-tidy-up-get-update  
  
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/20/get-windows-update-status-information-by-using-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I'll share what I found when solving this problem in the hopes that others may find it useful.

This behavior is the result of PowerShell not returning an array/collection when a single object is returned from the WHERE clause.  In my screenshot below I did a test using similar code and broke it down by each MsrcSeverity level.  The uncategorized severity had a single update in it but PowerShell returned a null value when I attempted to get the count.

You can also see that by calling the $uncategorizedupdates variable I am shown the actual update and not a collection.

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cha8z.png)

To fix this issue, all we have to do is explicitly define our variable as an [array] and then it will return a collection of objects even if only a single object is present.  Just modify your code as shown below....

```
[array]$critical = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq "Critical" }
[array]$important = $SearchResult.updates | where { $_.MsrcSeverity -eq "Important" }
[array]$optional = $SearchResult.updates | where { ($_.MsrcSeverity -ne "Critical") -and ($_.MsrcSeverity -ne "Important") }
```

I have reproduced this on Windows 10 as well so it is still an issue even in PowerShell 5.  Hope this is helpful.